# The code reads the file from the specified offset to the specified number of bytes. How to handle errors of partial reads in reading a file

Tags: c, linux, unix

I could like to read a file from a specified offset to a certain number of bytes in a file. I would pass the filename, the offset, the number of bytes as an argument. The constraint is should use only  read, write, open, and close system call. Could anyone say whether the code would handle the test case of bytes > buf_size and partial reads? I am beginner in Linux. Thanks a ton.

````
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<error.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#define buf_size 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int bytes;
    int offset;
    int fd; 
    int i = 0; 
    int length = 0;
    ssize_t read_bytes;
    char *file;
    char buf[buf_size];
    char *bufp;

    if (argc != 4)
        error(1, 0, "Too many or less than the number of arguments");
    file = argv[1];
    offset = atoi(argv[2]);
    bytes = atoi(argv[3]);
    fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
        error(1, errno, "Error while opening the file\n");
    read(fd, buf, offset);
    do {            
        read_bytes = read(fd, buf, bytes);
        if (read_bytes == -1)
                error(1, errno, "Error while reading the file\n");
        if (read_bytes == 0)
            return 0;
        for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
                putchar(buf[i]);
        if (close(fd) == -1)
                    error(1, 0, "Error while closing the file\n");
    } while (read_bytes != 0);
}
```
````

Comment: @pacmaninbw Thanks. I tested it, it works fine. Will there be any suggestions to improve the code.

Comment: The line ``read(fd, buf, offset);`` will fail if offset is bigger than buf_size (corrupt the stack), you should do this read in chunks of buf_size. The rest should be all right on first look but from a performance point of view, buf_size should be 4K or a multiple thereof.

Comment: So you've verified the following "Could anyone say whether the code would handle the test case of bytes > buf_size and partial reads"?

Comment: Because it doesn't look like it.

Comment: @Mast Yes, I misunderstood it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bug

In this loop the file is closed, this means that on the next iteration of the loop the read will fail.

```
    do {
        read_bytes = read(fd, buf, bytes);
        if (read_bytes == -1)
            error(1, errno, "Error while reading the file\n");
        if (read_bytes == 0)
            return 0;
        for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
            putchar(buf[i]);
        if (close(fd) == -1)
            error(1, 0, "Error while closing the file\n");
    } while (read_bytes != 0);
```

### Complexity

The function `main()` is too complex (does too much). As programs grow in size the use of `main()` should be limited to calling functions that parse the command line, calling functions that set up for processing, calling functions that execute the desired function of the program, and calling functions to clean up after the main portion of the program.

There is also a programming principle called the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) that applies here. The Single Responsibility Principle states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

There are at least 2 possible functions in `main()`.
  - Parse the command line arguments
  - Read the file using the offset and size

### The Code is Not Portable

The header files `error.h` and `unistd.h` are not portable, and any code that derives from them such as the function `error()` do not port to systems such as windows. In the case of `error()` it would be better to report the error to `stderr` using `fprintf()` and since this is in `main()` `return 1;` or if `stdlib.h` is included `return EXIT_FAILURE;`. Note that while `error()` is not portable, `perror()` is portable since it is part of the C programming standard.

### Understandable Error Messages

It is quite common to have a check on `argc`, but the error message provided usually provides the correct calling of the program as an example. The error message `Too many or less than the number of arguments` really doesn't tell the user enough, such as what arguments are missing, and what order they should be in.

```
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: readbytes Offset Bytes to read");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;    // since stdlib.h is included
    }
```

### More User Friendly

The program could be a little more user friendly if it was more flexible, rather than expecting Offset as `argv[2]` and Bytes to Read as `argv[3] Use -O for`offset`and -B for`Bytes to Read`.